# AngularJS: change element contents based on current view

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'd like to change the contents of a menu based on the view/page that is currently open. If my HTML looks like this;

```
<body ng-app='TestApp'>
    <menu-list></menu-list>

    <ng-view></ng-view>
</body>
```

Within a view, I'd like to set the menu;

```
<a top-menu-item ui-sref='about'>About</a>
<a top-menu-item ng-click='deleteCurrent()'>Delete</a>
```

The challenge for me is that the menu items contain code such as ui-sref or ng-click. Also, the menu item may link to another page using ui-sref, or perform a function using ng-click. What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Put the menu inside the view. Being different for depending on the view, it logically belongs there. And it's clearer - AngularJS aims for a declarative approach, so it should be clear what the menu will be when you look at the menu html. Changing it through code based on some parameters isn't really consistent with that approach.